What is the structure that is stored in UDP socket's send/receive buffers?
I noticed that receive and send buffers of UDP sockets have an overhead of approximately 600 bytes. That is, when I write 10 bytes of data to UDP socket, the actual structure stored in send/receive buffers has a size of 768 bytes. So the questions are:

What is actually stored in send/receive buffers?
Is there a way to get number of overhead bytes from C code
How many packets of size X bytes, can be stored in receive buffer, before it gets overflown?

Here is a small demo:
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in addr{
    .sin_family = AF_INET,
    .sin_port = htons(8080),
    .sin_addr = INADDR_ANY,
    .sin_zero = {},
};
sendto(fd, "0123456789", 10, 0, (sockaddr*)(&addr), sizeof(addr));

Socket that was bound to port number 8080 has its receive buffer populated with 768 bytes of data:
> netstat -anu | grep 8080
udp      768      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*


that's probably just the allocation granularity. Not sure it makes sense to consider this "static" per-packet-overhead.

this is Linux, I presume?

that is linux, thank you! Added new tag

There's no general C interface for that information; it's an operating system implementation detail, not "API" for application programmers.
For Linux:
You can just write a minimal kernel module that printk("size of a kernel packet buffer: %d\n", sizeof sk_buff); in its initialization and read dmesg when you load that to figure out the size of the data structure that holds all the metadata (not the data itself, only a pointer to it) of any network packet in the kernel.
The kernel's struct sock holds pointers to queues of these structures for receive, transmit and error queues for every socket.
You 768 B is really very likely due to the allocation granularity, and not the actual metadata overhead.
Again, you, as a userspace program developer, never see this data (aside from interacting with it using the libc calls to interact with the socket).
It might not be extremely wise to focus on that size, either: If your system's performance is limited by memory usage of network buffers, chances are you're doing something architecturally suboptimal, and should use a different interface than UNIX/BSD sockets to interact with the Linux network stack altogether.
